# Replace all whitespaces for one, but preserve the break lines

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to create a regex that will replace all white spaces for one, but preserving new lines, is possible?

for example:

```
var text = 'AAAAAAAA'
text += 'AA AA      AAA BB  B  B B B BB B'
text += 'B B';

var text = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
"AAAAAAAAAA AA      AAA BB  B  B B B BB BB B"
```

output:

```
"AAAAAAAAAA AA AAA BB B B B B BB BB B"
```

And i want preserve the lines.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want newlines you need \n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this,

```
text.replace(/[ \t]+/g, ' ');
```

or

```
text.replace(/(?:(?![\r\n])\s)+/g, ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the following characters are considered as *white spaces*:

- `\t` - tab
- `\f` - form feed
- `\r` - carriage return
- `\n` - line feed
- `\v` - vertical tab
- - space

You may use the following pattern to accomplish your task,

```
/[\t\f\v ]+/g
```

Eg.

```
text.replace(/[\t\f\v ]+/g, " ");
```